# Analytic continuation in the Hardy class of analytic functions arcoss the boundary

Tags: analytic-continuation, hardy-spaces

I have the following question, which I need help addressing.

If $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $D\subset\mathbb{C}$, with $\partial U\cap\partial D=\Gamma\neq\emptyset$ of positive measure, are open connected domains and $G:U\to\mathbb{C}$, $F:D\to\mathbb{C}$ such that

- $G$ is holomorphic on $U$,
- $F$ is holomorphic on $D$,
- $G$ has non-tangential boundary values $\tilde{G}$ a.e. on $\partial U$ with $\tilde{G}\in L^p(\partial U)$ for some $p>0$,
- $F$ has non-tangential boundary values $\tilde{F}$ a.e. on $\Gamma$ with $\tilde{F}\in L^p(\Gamma)$,
- $\tilde{F}=\tilde{G}$ a.e. on $\Gamma$,
- F is the analytic extension of $G$ across $\Gamma$, which means that eventually, $G$ is holomorphic on an open neighborhood of $\Gamma$ and that the analytic extension coincides with $F$,
- $F\in H^p(D)$, where $H^p(D)$ is the [Smirnov Class](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Smirnov_class) of analytic functions on $D$.

Are these conditions enough for us to have $G\in H^p(U)$?

Comment: No. Slightly rephrased, your set-up is the following: $F,G$ are restrictions of a single function $f$, let's say on the unit disk, and then $D, U$ could be the upper and lower semi-disks. Now you are basically asking if $f\in L^p$ on the upper semi-circle implies the same condition on the lower semi-circle, but of course there are no such restrictions.

Comment: Any $g\ge 0 \in L^p$, $\int \log g>-\infty$ is the absolute value of the boundary value of an $H^p$ function.

Comment: @ChristianRemling What about if we suppose that $\tilde{G}\in L^p(\partial U)$ (that is what I meant from the beginning)

Comment: I don't think this changes anything. In my example, this just means $f$ is $L^p$ on the upper semi-circle and on $(-1,1)$, this won't control $f$ on the lower semi-circle.